# Print multidimentional array from query result

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach, while-loop

I have an array:-

```
$resolution = array();
foreach ($report as $key => $val) {
    $queryToGetRes = "SELECT resolution,ticket_no FROM techzilla.bugs WHERE bug_id = '$val' ";
    $sqlResult = mysql_query($queryToGetRes) or die (mysql_error());
    while ($resolutionAns = mysql_fetch_array($sqlResult)) {
             $resolution[$resolutionAns['resolution']][] = $resolutionAns['ticket_no'];
    }
  }
```

I need to print the array which stores the resolution and ticket no.

Comment: echo '<pre>' ;just call print_r($resolution);
you might know PHP print function. What is the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
echo "<pre>" . print_r($resolution, true) . "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

For debuging purpuses you should use

```
var_dump($resolution);
```

If you want to use it

```
foreach ($resolution as $r => $ids){
    echo "Resolution : $r\n";
    foreach ($ids as $id) {
        echo "$id\n";
    }
}
```